# Loading 'theme' and 'exporting' module with Highcharts using Requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, requirejs, amd

I have tried several different configurations of my paths and shim attributes in my requirejs.config function but none seem to load my gray.js theme and the exporting.js module. Currently I have:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'static/js',
    paths: {
        'jquery' : 'jquery-1.7.2.min',
        'highcharts' : ['HighCharts/highcharts',
                         'HighCharts/themes/gray',
                         'HighCharts/modules/exporting']
    },
    shim: {
        'highcharts': {
            'exports': 'Highcharts',
            'deps': ['jquery']
         }
    }        
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't break gray.js and exporting.js out into their own paths and add them to the highcharts shim as deps because they rely on highcharts.

I am thinking about making the 'highcharts' shortcut in paths point to exporting.js and make gray.js and highcharts.js deps of it, but this seems a little confusing. Like the following. Thoughts?

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'static/js',
    paths: {
        'jquery' : 'jquery-1.7.2.min',
        'highcharts' : 'HighCharts/modules/exporting',
        'highcharts-theme': 'HighCharts/themes/gray',
        'highcharts-module': 'HighCharts/highcharts'
    },
    shim: {
        'highcharts-module': {
            'exports': 'Highcharts',
            'deps': ['jquery']
         },
        'highcharts': {
            'deps': ['highcharts-module', 'highcharts-theme']
        }
    }
});
```

### UPDATE:

My page html (abbreviated):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" >
   <head>
      <script src="/static/js/require.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
      <script src="/static/js/requirejs.config.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="#myChart"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript"> 
         require(['jquery','domReady', 'highcharts'], function($, domReady, Highcharts){
            domReady(function(){
               //Stuff to draw Chart here
            });
         });
      </script>
   </body>
```

Comment: what do you have in your main html and main js files? where do you call define?

Comment: this line:  'highcharts' : ['HighCharts/highcharts',
                         'HighCharts/themes/gray',
                         'HighCharts/modules/exporting'] doesn't express a dependency, but a 'paths fallback' - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pathsfallbacks

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification on the paths fallback. I saw other people doing it this way and was like, I didn't see dependencies like that in the docs - cause they're not, ha.

Comment: I did get something working using my second config example. Its kind of like reverse dependencies. I'll post that answer if no one comes up with something prettier.

Comment: Have you seen this related topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186027/loading-highcharts-with-require-js

Comment: Yes, but it does not talk about loading a theme and the exporting module along with highcharts. The problem is not loading highcharts, its loading all three, while sorting dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "scripts/",
    paths: {
        "highcharts": "lib/highcharts-src",
        'highcharts-theme': 'lib/dark-unica'
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: 'jQuery'
        },
        highcharts: {
            deps: ['lib/jquery'],
            exports: 'Highcharts'
        },
        'highcharts-theme': {
            deps: ['highcharts'],
            exports: 'Highcharts'
        }
    }
});
```

this way you can do

```
define(['highcharts-theme'],function( ...
```

or if you need it without the theme somewhere

```
define(['highcharts'],function( ...
```

Comment: `deps` is an array of Strings, not a String. That always trips me up when there's a single dependency and I forget.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly simpler perhaps:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'static/js',
    paths: {
        'jquery' : 'jquery-1.7.2.min',
        'highcharts' : 'HighCharts/modules/exporting',
    },
    shim: {
        'HighCharts/highcharts': {
            'exports': 'Highcharts',
            'deps': ['jquery']
         },
        'highcharts': {
            'deps': ['HighCharts/highcharts', 'HighCharts/themes/gray']
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem with this setup is that the theme can load before highcharts.js. I also found that you have to specify the export on the 'highcharts' shim itself, not the HighCharts/highcharts shim.

Answer (score 0):

I finally implemented the following solution. @Lyn Headley, your solution doesn't solve the dependency that highcharts.js needs to be loaded before the theme, but thanks again for clarifying the Paths Fallback syntax.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'static/js',
    paths: {
        'jquery' : 'jquery-1.7.2.min',
        'highcharts' : 'HighCharts/modules/exporting',
        'highcharts-theme': 'HighCharts/themes/gray',
        'highcharts-module': 'HighCharts/highcharts'
    },
    shim: {
        'highcharts-module': {           // This allows users to only import highcharts 
            'exports': 'Highcharts',     //   without theme or exporting module.
            'deps': ['jquery']
         },                                        // Make sure highcharts.js is loaded
        'highcharts-theme': ['highcharts-module'], //   before the theme is.
        'highcharts': {
            'deps': ['highcharts-module', 'highcharts-theme'],
            'exports': 'Highcharts'      // Still gotta make this available
        }
    }
});
```