# Highcharts not accessible when loaded as AMD Module with requireJS

Tags: javascript, highcharts, requirejs

How do I correctly access Highcharts when I load it as an AMD Module using requireJS? I was under the impression that I was supposed to do it like this:

```
define(["../js/highcharts/highcharts","css!../css/component.css"], 
  function(Highcharts, css) {
      console.log(Highcharts);
});
```

The output is this:

```
undefined
```

Am I calling or initializing it incorrectly?

Comment: First thing to confirm is that the path to highcharts is correct.

Comment: Unless things have changed (very possible) I believe that Highcharts will need a shim config to work with requireJS. [See this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186027/loading-highcharts-with-require-js).

Comment: @DFriend thanks for the tip. and yeah, the path is correct. I got a bunch of errors when it wasn't. No errors with this code