# How to create graph with Backbone.js and Require.js

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, graph

I am working on a project where I need to create a graph with some json data. I could fetch data from a json file but not able to create graph with it as I am really new to backbone.js

```
 var HomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        url: 'http://localhost:1337/api/getData',

    });


    var HomeModel = new HomeModel();
        var params;
    HomeModel.fetch({
        success: function(response,xhr) {
             var params = JSON.stringify(response);
           console.log (params);
           return params;

        },
        error: function (errorResponse) {
               console.log(errorResponse)
        }
    });
 return HomeModel;

}
```

In view file:

```
define(["jquery", "backbone", "models/HomeModel", "text!templates/Home.html"],

    function($, Backbone, Model, template, opts){
   console.log(Model);

        var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '#sample-template',
                initialize: function(opts) {
                    this.template = opts.template;
                    this.render();
                    console.log('ini',Model);
                },
                render: function () {
                    var template = _.template($('#sample-template').html());
                    $('#sample-template').html(template(JSON.stringify(Model)));
                }

            });



            var HomeView = new HomeView({
                model: Model, 
                el: '.magic',
            });

         return HomeView;

    }

);
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should charting libraries like highcharts or d3.js for plotting your data

Comment: Thanks for your comment @cdoshi. I have seen some example on it but couldn't figure out how to accomplish it. If there is any simple example, can you please provide me?

Comment: You would need to shim highcharts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186027/loading-highcharts-with-require-js

and then you can include it in your backbone view and use it like http://jsfiddle.net/V7jQD/

Comment: @cdoshi thank you so much for your help. After implementing accordingly, I am getting following error. "HomeView.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: this.$el.highcharts is not a function"..I have required shim highcharts too.

Comment: You cannot use it exactly like in JSfiddle. First check if you are able to import Highcharts correctly. In your view, console.log highcharts to see if you can access it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create graph using Backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508827/how-to-create-graph-using-backbone-js)